# Accordion menu submenu interaction

Tags: jquery, accordion

I want to produce an accordion where a submenu item will expand when I click on it. My problem is everytime I expand my submenus, the menu item just keep toggling off. It toggles the submenus BUT I have to expand the menu again to just to see it.

Here is my HTML :

```
<div class="fs_menu_overlay"></div>
<div class="hamburger_menu">
  <div class="hamburger_close"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div class="hamburger_menu_content text-right">
    <ul class="menu_top_nav">
      <li class="menu_item has-children">
        <a href="#" class="anchor-head">
          <!-- Populated by javascript -->
        </a>
        <ul class="menu_selection">
          <!-- Populated by javascript -->
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="menu_item has-children">
        <a href="#clothing" class="submenu" data-toggle="collapse">CLOTHING <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
          <ul id="clothing" class="menu_selection">
            <li class="submenu_item has-subchildren"><a href="#menclothing" data-toggle="collapse">MEN'S CLOTHING <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                <ul id="menclothing" class="menu_selection">
                  <li><a href="#">TSHIRTS</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">POLO SHIRTS</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">JACKETS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="submenu_item has-subchildren"><a href="#womenclothing" data-toggle="collapse">WOMEN'S CLOTHING <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                <ul id="womenclothing" class="menu_selection">
                <li><a href="#">DRESSES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SKIRTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TOPS</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Jquery:

```
if($('.menu_item').length)
    {
        var items = document.getElementsByClassName('menu_item');
        var i;

        for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        {
            if(items[i].classList.contains("has-children"))
            {
                items[i].onclick = function()
                {

                    this.classList.toggle("active");
                    var panel = this.children[1];
                    if(panel.style.maxHeight)
                    {
                        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
                    }


                }
            }
        }
    }

    if($('.submenu_item').length)
    {
        var subitems = document.getElementsByClassName('submenu_item');
        var i;

        for(i = 0; i < subitems.length; i++)
        {
            if(subitems[i].classList.contains("has-subchildren"))
            {
                subitems[i].onclick = function()
                {

                    this.classList.toggle("active");
                    var panel = this.children[1];
                    if(panel.style.maxHeight)
                    {
                        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
                    }


                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't want to use plugin because it might affect the HTML with the comment `Populated by Javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on '.submenu_item', the event also bubbles to the parent elements. That means the '.menu_item' will also receive a click event. You should try to use stopPropagation() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation on '.submenu_item'

Comment: where should I put it sir? inside `subitems[i].onclick = function()`?

Comment: i tried putting it in inside `subitems[i].onclick = function()` and it seems my submenu_item are not expanding as I thought.

Comment: Did you try something like this `subitems[i].onclick = function(event) { event.stopPropagation(); // the other codes ...`

Comment: Also, you shouldn't mix jQuery with vanilla JS. Toggling classes and moving style changes to those classes is also better in my opinion. I've created a very simple pen for your case, you can take a look here https://codepen.io/baott/pen/jpOmZO

Comment: I tried `subitems[i].onclick = function(event) { event.stopPropagation(); // the other codes ...` but the maxheight of the `submenu_item` is not expanding. I have to toggle it again to make `submenu_item` expand.